# Cannot add or update a child row :

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

Im trying to run following SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE przedmiot
ADD FOREIGN KEY (nauczyciel) REFERENCES nauczyciel(id_nauczyciel);
```

Table "przedmiot":

[image]

Table "nauczyciel":

[image]

Error:
Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`zi2`.`#sql-185c_9`, CONSTRAINT `przedmiot_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`nauczyciel`) REFERENCES `nauczyciel` (`id_nauczyciel`))

Comment: Is there already data in these tables? Are there values in przedmiot.nauczyciel that don't have a corresponding value in nauczyciel.id_nauczyciel?

Comment: @NickW Yes. I deleted them and it worked. Thank you so much!